# Getting firebase database data by their token

Tags: react-native

I have pushed some data into firebase database and each have a unique key. I can get the key but how can I get only the data under certain key like

```
let databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Names')
const key = 'M4s4jtJza2K1f4P5Q'
```

How can I get data under `key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read more in this link https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

database()
  .ref('/Names/M4s4jtJza2K1f4P5Q')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried but it givese me null.

Comment: Could you screen shot key and tree in firebase?